# Linking to AWS S3 direct image uploads in Django templates

Tags: django, amazon-s3

I'm using AWS S3 buckets for my images in my Django project through django-storages.

It's pretty clear how to show an image in a template that has been uploaded through a model ImageField. Just do e.g.

```
<img src="{{ model.image.url }}">
```

What if, however, I upload an image on S3 directly (e.g. for the website logo) and want to show it in a template? Any better way to just hardcoding the absolute Amazon S3 path:

```
<img src="https://myapp.s3.amazonaws.com/home/logo.png">
```

Is there some way I can use just the relative "/home/logo.png" without hardcoding the amazonaws subdomain?

**EDIT:** Currently this is what's in my settings.py file:

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

My static files are collected on Heroku in a /staticfiles/ directory, and all model ImageField uploads end up in S3...

When I do `python manage.py collectfiles` as suggested [here](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/08/01/how-to-setup-amazon-s3-in-a-django-project.html) all that happens is that all static files are also copied to my local /staticfiles/ directory.

Answer (score 1):

You should not need to hard code that! I don't know the specifics of your setup, but maybe it'd help if you took a look at [this article](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/08/01/how-to-setup-amazon-s3-in-a-django-project.html). Specifically the settings.py part.

Comment: I did come across that - thanks. This doesn't work in my case. Instead of uploading local media files to S3, I get remote static files from Heroku downloaded to my local /staticfiles/ folder...I added some details on my settings.py file on my original post.

Answer (score 0):

The website logo should go into VCS (Version control, your repository), inside a `static` or whatever you want to name it folder. Then, when you do your `python manage.py collectstatic`, the files will be uploaded to S3. After that, you can simply do the following in your template:

```
{% load static %}
<img src="{% static 'img/logo.png' %}" alt="logo">
```

Comment: Thanks, @Dalvtor. I made some edits to my original post. When I do collectstatic all that happens is my remote static files (not media files) are collected to my local /staticfiles/ folder.